# Special Case of Matrix multiplication Using CUDA

Tags: cuda, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication, cublas, matrix-decomposition

I am searching for some special functions (CUDA) that dedicate to typical dense matrix multiplications, e.g. A*B, where the size of A is 6*n, the size of B is n*6 and n is very large (n=2^24). I have utilized CUBLAS and some other libraries to test this example, In CUBLAS, for this example, we use 6*6=36 threads, which is far from the total parallelism of GPU, so I split A and B into submatrices(vectors) and then implement dot product function for each of them and the performance has been quite well improved. The problem is, in this case, we need to launch 36 CUDA kernels and in between them there are a lot of same data footprints (same data has been accessed for several times from the global memory of GPU). So I am asking whether there exists any solution to this kind of problem.

Comment: I think since the OP deleted all question text, the question is now useless and unlikely to help any future visitors.  Vote to close as "too localized" due to this deletion.  I might add that @tera gave a good answer and I believe it should have been accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently written such a matrix multiplication routine for a client of mine. The trick is to extract more parallelism by splitting the long inner summation into several smaller ones. Then use a separate kernel launch to calculate the full sum from the partial ones.

Comment: As you noticed having just 36 threads does not fill the GPU. If you split the summation in the matrix multiplication into m partial sums and perform each of them in a separate thread, you have a total of m*36 threads. Choosing m sufficiently large then allows to fully load the GPU.

Comment: How are you caching 2^24 values in shared memory?

Comment: There just isn't enough shared memory on the entire GPU to cache 2^24 values, regardless of how many blocks you create. Are you familiar with the [programming model of CUDA](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#scalable-programming-model) and how it maps to the hardware?

Comment: The numbers are correct, but these blocks do not all execute in parallel. Once the available shared memory (or other limiting resource) is used up, further blocks only execute when other blocks finish and free up their resources.